# Size advice needed for Revolution Country Traveller touring bike

Tags: frames, touring, touring-bikes, advice

I'm about to by my first touring bike. I've got a very tight budget so I will probably order a Revolution Country Traveller from Edinburgh bicycle cooperation as it looks like it will suit my needs.

Though I would like some tips for which frame size I should choose. I know it's really hard for anyone to say what I will like the best but I've got no possibility of trying out the bike before buying. I haven't got any bikeshop nearby with a very similar bike in stock neither.

I'm 20 years old, between 177-178 cm tall and my leg length (to my crotch) is about 80 - 81 centimeters. I've go a Specialized MTB with 19" frame which I feel suits me well and I've got a Nishiki Criterium (2008 or 2009 year model) in size "medium" which has a seat tube length of about 50 centimeters or so. And I feel quite comfortable on that bike as well.

If I use the formulas based on my leg length I get results ranging between 53 - 55 centimeters. The Country Traveller is available in either 52 or 55 centimeters.

So, just by looking at what I've written above, what would you guess would be the best for me? I'm by the way not a very experienced cyclist. Even though I have had my Criterium quite a while I haven't travelled very great distances on it so I'm still quite inexperienced in general.

All tips and comments are most welcome!

I apologize to all americans for using imperial measurement units by the way. But hey, google is your friend! ;)

Comment: Did you try contacting the shop to see what they have to say about that specific bike?  Unless somebody on this site owns that specific bike, we probably won't be able to help you much, as [the site](http://www.edinburghbicycle.com/products/revolution-country-traveller-15) doesn't seem to give very specific measurements of the various frame dimensions.

Comment: I've been in contact with them and based from what I could tell them about myself they thought the 52 centimeter frame would perhaps be the better choice. 

Yes, you're probably right about that it's hard to give me any advice if you don't own the specific bike. But IF anyone here actually would own the bike they could maybe have some useful advice

Comment: I still think this is too broad - voting to close.

Comment: What seems odd is that somebody who is 5'9" would be on the smallest model. You aren't short, so I wonder what they would recommend for a short person. Based on the [sizing guide](http://www.edinburghbicycle.com/info/bike-sizing-guide/#bikes-touring) it looks like you would be on the 55 cm.

Comment: @Kibbee Yes that's what I was thinking as well and that's what made me doubt. But perhaps both sizes would work. It's a pity that no nearby bike shops are having any touring bikes.

Comment: I have the same inside leg as you but am 5cm shorter overall. When I look for a bike I'll start at 53/54cm and work from there. If this information helps you, great. If it doesn't, there's a reason...

Comment: @PeteH Thank for your feedback! Yeah, my legs aren't that long but my back is quite long I guess. I've sent the store a new mail to see if I can get some more measurements of the bike before I make up my mind.

Answer (score 1):

The other question to ask is the length of the top tube and how that compares with what you have.  I agree with Kibbee that it sounds like with an 80 cm inseam, you should be on the larger bike.  Still, it is easier to get a long stem on a smaller bike if it fits otherwise.